# Convert csv files,text files,pdf files into json using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario in which I'm pulling files from different sources, The files are in text,csv,json and pdf format. I'm pulling these files by using copy data activity of ADF. Now, the files should be loaded into cosmos db into the same table. I'm able to load the JSON files in cosmos db but other files format cannot feed into cosmos db. so I'm trying to convert other files into JSON but no help. I have gone through custom activity solution but due to some restriction I'm not able to complete the solution.

Please let me know is there any way to transform text,csv,pdf files into JSON and can be feed into cosmos db.

Answer (score 2):

Data Factory can convert the .csv file to .json during file copy active.

For example:

Source dataset:

[image]

Sink dataset:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Mapping:
[image]

Pipeline Running:
[image]

Check the new json file in the container:

[image]

This example just want to tell you that Data Factory can help convert some format data to .json file. But not all the files can be converted. You must test by yourself and get the answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My bad I just checked for csv files and in that we don't need anything in cosmos db. The csv file is directly converting into array of objects before dumping into cosmos db. I just want some suggestion how can I convert other file formats, I did go through the custom activity and able to run basic python script in custom activity but for some complex program containing external module like pandas,azure. It's giving me error that module not found.

Comment: @sam Some other ways is that we can using Data Flow [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) expression to build a json format data, then copy it to sink blob.  When run other scripts in Data Factory, there are many limits and error we may get. For this kind of questions, often have no solutions.

Comment: I believe custom activity can be a solution once data get downloaded in blob and while pulling from blob. we may convert it into csv or json formats and feed into the cosmos db.

Comment: @sam You may need test this by yourself. I suggest you post it as another question, maybe others can give your more ideas.

Comment: sure I am checking other resources as well. Let see if it's possible to achieve above requirement.

Comment: @sam I also hope you could get a better answer. You can waiting for some days. In the end,  if my answer is helpful for you,  can you please vote up or mark  it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Setting the file pattern to "Array of objects" helped me to solve mine issue! Thanks