# How to integrate Python Code in Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Text delimited file in my Azure data factory. I have to convert it to a json file.
I also have a python code that converts my text delimited file to a json file.
Now how do I integrate this python code in azure data factory. How to run this code from ADF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure Data Factory Data Flow to do a lot of transforms like csv to JSON without Python (see this answer: [Convert csv files,text files,pdf files into json using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61057965/convert-csv-files-text-files-pdf-files-into-json-using-azure-data-factory)).

If you need the control Python offers, you can use Azure Batch to run your python file.  In your python, you can grab the csv from a blob using blob_client.download_blob() to bring it down to a local file on the batch VM.  Then you can load the file normally (pd.read_csv()) and do your transform.  After you write your json file locally, you can upload back to the blob and then do whatever other ADF actions you want.
I used this set of instructions to get started running Azure Batch python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python